# When type on an input field pass the text to another field using jquery or js

Tags: html, jquery

I have two input fields. I need every time i type inside first div to pass the text to the second field. The problem is that with my code below it cuts the last letter! What i 'm doing wrong ?

```js
$(".first").bind('keydown', function(e){
$(".second").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="first" placeholder="type here">
<input type="text" class="second" placeholder="here it is the result">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it cuts last letter

It's not that it's *cutting* the input: you're processing the textbox before your key press has updated the value - `keydown` occurs first.

Use `keyup` or a better replacement would be `input` which would also capture copy+paste etc

```js
$(".first").on('input', function(e) {
  $(".second").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="first" placeholder="type here">
<input type="text" class="second" placeholder="here it is the result">
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not cut, simple you are not focus on second but if you click on that and overflow to right you will see you have all complete word
i add example with `console.log`

```js
$(".first").on('input', function(e) {
$(".second").val($(this).val());
console.log($(".first").val()+' = ' + $(".second").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="first" placeholder="type here">
<input type="text" class="second" placeholder="here it is the result">
```

Comment: Enter "simone" in first box - what appears in the console.log?